# Can I get decent growth from turmeric doing no dig in USDA zone 4a?

Tags: herbs, hardiness-zone

I'm thinking about doing no dig turmeric in a wood chip bed that has moisture about 1 foot down, and was wondering if I should be successful growing turmeric growing in a wood chip bed I inoculated with Wine caps to aid in breaking down the wood chips. I've seen it done in clay bead beds, but don't know if I have good enough growing conditions.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of tumeric and ginger is they naturally want to grow large rhizomes or roots and the want to do it sideways maintaining the same depth, so if they have loose soil and space and get the water and sun they need they will try to expand sideways as much as they can

Comment: it's a temperature and growing season question